# Optimising tables for ordering from a join

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, index-tuning

Hopefully this is simpler for someone here than me, I am struggling how to optimise database where a query orders from the result of a join on MySQL. Below:

```
SELECT
  `n`.*,
  `c`.`author`,
  `c`.`title`,
  `c`.`body`,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.created) AS `created`,
  `c`.`commenting`,
  `c`.`deleted`,
  `c`.`sticky`,
  `u`.`screenName`,
  COUNT(cm.id) AS `comments_count`,
  `ph`.`file` AS `photo`
FROM
  `news` AS `n`
  INNER JOIN `contents` AS `c`
    ON c.id = n.content_id
  INNER JOIN `users` AS `u`
    ON u.id = c.author
  LEFT JOIN `comments` AS `cm`
    ON cm.hosting = c.id
    AND cm.type = "content"
    AND cm.deleted = 0
    AND cm.hidden = 0
  LEFT JOIN `photos` AS `ph`
    ON ph.id = n.photo_id
WHERE (main = 1)
  AND (c.deleted = 0)
  AND (c.approved = 1)
GROUP BY `n`.`id`
ORDER BY `c`.`sticky` DESC,
  `n`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

In this, if I remove the ORDER BY `sticky`, the query is near instant where as it takes about 6 seconds otherwise. I am not too sure what (if any) index I can put into place to help sort - I have tried indexing id and sticky, just sticky, and a bunch of shot in the dark combinations with no luck.

I have also tried index hinting however this doesn't appear to work with joined tables.

Comment: The reason the query is so fast without the order by is that the first 10 rows are projected.  The order by is forcing MySQL to obtain all the rows, sort them, then show the first 10 sorted rows.  In general, you will want to ensure the columns forming the heart of your join syntax are indexed.  Use "explain select..." to see what execution plan the query optimizer is producing.

Comment: consider indexing news.content_id, news.photo_id, contents.id, contents.author, users.id, comments.hosting, photos.id.

Answer (score 1):

"Explode (JOIN), Implode (GROUP BY)" is what I call it.

You can get rid of part of the explosion by changing

```
COUNT(cm.id) AS `comments_count`,
```

into

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE ...
) AS comments_count,
```

and getting rid of the `LEFT JOIN comments ON ...`.

If that does not speed it up enough, come back with the new `SELECT`, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT`, the table sizes, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be other things we can do to speed it up.  Is news:content in a 1:1 relationship?

Comment: +1. My thoughts exactly. Should be: *"getting rid of the `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN` ..."*